# CORS issue with website calling a REST API on https

Tags: spring-boot, rest, ssl, https, cors

I have a website running on `https`.
I want this website to communicate with a REST Api service running on a AWS EC2 server.
This service is implemented with Spring Boot and the Controller class contains the `@CrossOrigin` annotation with the origin website as a parameter.
However I am getting following error while doing a `POST` request from the website with the service listening on port `443` with a self signed certificate:

```
  Access to XMLHttpRequest at x from origin y has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

And following one while doing a `GET` request:

```
  Access to XMLHttpRequest at x from origin y has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I also declared `localhost` in the service `@CrossOrigin` annotation.

It is failing with same error as above if I have my service run on port `443` with a self signed certificate, but it is working fine if I have my service running on port `8080` without SSL.

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Also I guess that if I manage to solve the `CORS` issue I will still have a problem, as my certificate is self signed.
How can I install a public certificate for a REST Api running in EC2 for example?

Thanks!

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. Figure out how to use a proper certificate. The easiest might be to just set up an amazon load balancer, which supports this out of the box. Otherwise search keywords "spring boot letsencrypt"

Comment: Did you add your cert as trusted to the browser? Did you use localhost, or did your overwrite the hosts file? Localhost needs a special origin so better to avoid it if you don't want to use allow origin *, which is many times not recommended.

Comment: No I did not add the cert sa trusted to the browser. But if the issue is coming from the certificate, shouldn't I get other error than CORS error (like invalid or not public certificate)?

Answer (score -1):

Add the config mentioned below to your spring-boot project.

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("HEAD");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tugrul, but I am still getting same CORS error

Comment: Hi @user2708647 are you able to resolve this issue? I am having having exactly same problem